# Mirror greek symbol in math environment

Tags: unicode-math, greek

I need a mirrored symbol `\Gamma`. Is it posible? I can't find this symbol and I do not know a way to mirror the symbol. I use unicode math.

Comment: as egreg says, this symbol is not in unicode.  is the symbol in common use, and can you provide a citation for a published source?  if so, it can be submitted to unicode (i'm an official contact for this); see my profile for contact information.

Comment: @barbarabeeton See my answer for a source of such a symbol (a variant, actually).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `\reflectbox` from `graphicx` and also `\text` from `amsmath` to get the symbol to scale in sub/superscripts

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ammaG}{\text{\reflectbox{$\Gamma$}}}

\begin{document}

$\Gamma\ne\ammaG$

$\Gamma=\Gamma$

$\ammaG_{\ammaG_\ammaG}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's better to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` so there's no problem using the new symbol in moving arguments. Of course you can't copy-paste it as a reversed Gamma, but the symbol is not in Unicode anyway.

If one needs an “almost reflected” version of `\varGamma`, some pain is needed for kerning subscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\antivarGamma}{e{_^}}{%
  {\mathpalette\makeantigamma\relax}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\kernforantigamma{#1}}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makeantigamma}[2]{%
  \reflectbox{\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\m@th#1 L$}}}%
}
\newcommand{\kernforantigamma}[1]{\mathpalette\kern@for@antigamma{#1}}
\newcommand{\kern@for@antigamma}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\promote@style#1{\kern0ptI}_{#2}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th\promote@style#1I_{#2}$}%
  \kern\dimexpr\wd\tw@-\wd\z@ #2
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\promote@style}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\textstyle\else\scriptstyle\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$
-I_{kl}\antivarGamma_{m}=g_{km}\antivarGamma{l}-g_{lm}\antivarGamma_{k}
\qquad
\varGamma_{k}^{*}=\antivarGamma{k}^{\dagger}\varLambda
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\antivarGamma` symbol appears in a 1945 paper on the Dirac equation (Proceedings of the Royal Society). See [Is there a TeX symbol that looks like this reverse uppercase gamma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481077/4427)

[image]

Source: H. Chandra, “The correspondence between the particle and the wave aspects of the meson and the photon,” Proc. R. Soc. London, Ser. A 186(1007), 502–525 (1946).

Comment: `Package unicode-math Error: Cannot be run with pdfLaTeX!
(unicode-math)                Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead..` - I think you should at least note that in your answer.

Comment: @moose The OP said to be using `unicode-math`, so the answer applies to that setting. However, just remove the call to the package and the `\setmathfont` instruction: the macro will work.