# Is there a TeX symbol that looks like this reverse uppercase gamma?

Tags: symbols

I am reading a 1946 paper on the Dirac equation (H. Chandra, “The correspondence between the particle and the wave aspects of the meson and the photon,” Proc. R. Soc. London, Ser. A 186(1007), 502–525 (1946)) where a symbol that resembles a reverse uppercase gamma appears (see image). Is there a name for this symbol, and is there a comparable LaTeX symbol?

[image]

Comment: You can always define a reverse symbol from the original one, using something like `\reflectbox`, etc.

Comment: Thank you (from a relative newbie to LaTeX), this works perfectly to reproduce the reversed (reflected) uppercase symbol gamma.

Comment: Ah yes, beautiful.. a "mirrored" symbol, I didn't think of describing it that way. Thanks for the citation with code.

Comment: @splitcomplexes I added a version for the slanted symbol

Comment: @egreg - thanks again, very nice. I hadn't even noticed the slanted form in the paper, I was so thrilled to see that the mirrored symbol was so easy to construct via your instructions. This is very welcome icing on the cake.

Comment: @egreg - I edited my question to give a full citation to the article in which I found this mirrored varGamma, noticing that in the original question that I duplicated, Barbara Beaton had asked for such a reference. I don't have the status required to comment directly to her comment, perhaps you could do that for me if you think it would be of interest.

Comment: @splitcomplexes I added the reference also to my answer. Thanks for it.