# The mirror of \Sigma and \sqrt

Tags: macros

How can I get the mirror of `\Sigma` (Σ) for summation and `\sqrt` for the root
I want to write arabic equation from right to left with arabic number.
I have used:
`\reflectbox{\sqrt}`, but does not work. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Very many thanks Mr. M. Al Jumaily, I use only the realy arabic number system {1,2,3,...}
can you please add the arabic Trigonometric functions with amiri font
`{,...,جا,جتا, ظا} `with exponent parameter as optional argument for the command.
i can not get the exponent very near the Trigonometric functions

Answer (score 2):

### Edit 3 (Including sin function)

[image: Output including sin function]

```
% Run in XeLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Make sure you import your packages before fontspec, polyglossia, etc.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%\usepackage{showframe} % Not needed! To show the borders of paper
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Arabic font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.0,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri}
% Note Mapping=arabicdigits will change all the numbers 
% to arabic numbers to ٠ ١ ٢ ٣ ٤ ٥ ٦ ٧ ٨ ٩.

% The following fixes the parentheses around the equation numbers.
\newtagform{arabicparentheses}{)}{(}
\usetagform{arabicparentheses}

% Flips the text about the y axis by 180 degrees.
\newcommand{\adj}[1]{\rotatebox{180}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{#1}}}

% In-text sqrt with the nth root option
\newcommand{\arabicsqrt}[2][]{%
    \adj{\ensuremath{\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}\adj{#1}]{\adj{#2}}}}%
}%
% larger sqrt with the nth root option
\newcommand{\arabicSqrt}[2][]{%
    \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}\adj{#1}]{\adj{#2}}}}%
}%
% In-text summation
\newcommand{\arabicsigma}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\sum_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% larger summation
\newcommand{\arabicSigma}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sum_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% In-text integral
\newcommand{\arabicint}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\int_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% Larger summation
\newcommand{\arabicInt}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\int_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%

% Sin
\DeclareMathOperator{\arabicSin}{\textup{\textbf{جا}}}
\newcommand{\SIN}[2][]{\ensuremath{\text{\begin{Arabic}#2‎\end{Arabic}}^\text{\begin{Arabic}#1\end{Arabic}}\arabicSin}}

\begin{document}
% random text!
$\SIN[3]{س}$
بحث في للصين مهمّات, دول و ووصف أهّل. بحشد اللازمة شيء مع,
 أي إعلان ويتّفق كان, دأبوا والفرنسي قد لها.
  وترك لغات الحيلولة أن بال, واحدة الخاطفة المعاهدات لكل عل.
  من تلك يطول أجزاء بالسيطرة, بحق انتهت الشتاء وتنصيب قد.\\
\arabicsqrt[4]{\arabicsqrt[2]{س + 3}}\\
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \centerline{text-mode}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}\\
            arabicsqrt  & \arabicsqrt{42}\\[1.4em]
            arabicSqrt  & \arabicSqrt{31}\\[1.4em]
            arabicsqrt  & \arabicsqrt[3]{42}\\[1.4em]
            arabicSqrt  & \arabicSqrt[3]{31}\\[1.4em]
            arabicsigma & \arabicsigma{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.4em]
            arabicSigma & \arabicSigma{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[2.2em]
            arabicint   & \arabicint{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.8em]
            arabicInt   & \arabicInt{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[2.5em]
            SIN         & Non-existence
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \centerline{mathmode}\vspace{-17pt}
        \begin{align}
            \text{arabicsqrt}       &= \arabicsqrt{42}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicSqrt}       &= \arabicSqrt{31}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicsqrt}       &= \arabicsqrt[3]{42}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicSqrt}       &= \arabicSqrt[3]{31}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicsigma}  &= \arabicsigma{س}{ب}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicSigma}  &= \arabicSigma{س}{ب}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicint}        &= \arabicint{س}{ب}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicInt}        &= \arabicInt{س}{ب}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \text{SIN}              &= \SIN[3]{س}
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

### Edit 2 (A complete Arabic example)

I have gathered a nice and minimal working example which takes care of the basic needs. First, I added `\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}` to the definition of `\arabicsqrt` and `\arabicSqrt` to change the positioning of the nth root. Secondly, Arabic text/numbers with parentheses don't work well at all. Hence, it has been taken care of. Randomly copied and pasted Arabic text is shown by the way :).

[image: Arabic Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Make sure you import your packages before fontspec, polyglossia, etc.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{showframe} % Not needed! To show the borders of paper
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Arabic font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.0,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri}
% Note Mapping=arabicdigits will change all the numbers 
% to arabic numbers to ٠ ١ ٢ ٣ ٤ ٥ ٦ ٧ ٨ ٩.

% The following fixes the parentheses around the equation numbers.
\newtagform{arabicparentheses}{)}{(}
\usetagform{arabicparentheses}

% Flips the text about the y axis by 180 degrees.
\newcommand{\adj}[1]{\rotatebox{180}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{#1}}}

% In-text sqrt with the nth root option
\newcommand{\arabicsqrt}[2][]{%
    \adj{\ensuremath{\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}\adj{#1}]{\adj{#2}}}}%
}%
% larger sqrt with the nth root option
\newcommand{\arabicSqrt}[2][]{%
    \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{2}\adj{#1}]{\adj{#2}}}}%
}%
% In-text summation
\newcommand{\arabicsigma}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\sum_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% larger summation
\newcommand{\arabicSigma}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sum_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% In-text integral
\newcommand{\arabicint}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\int_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% Larger summation
\newcommand{\arabicInt}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\int_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%

\begin{document}
% random text!
بحث في للصين مهمّات, دول و ووصف أهّل. بحشد اللازمة شيء مع,
 أي إعلان ويتّفق كان, دأبوا والفرنسي قد لها.
  وترك لغات الحيلولة أن بال, واحدة الخاطفة المعاهدات لكل عل.
  من تلك يطول أجزاء بالسيطرة, بحق انتهت الشتاء وتنصيب قد.\\
\arabicsqrt[4]{\arabicsqrt[2]{س + 3}}\\
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \centerline{In text-mode}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            arabicsqrt  & \arabicsqrt{42}\\[1.2em]
            arabicSqrt  & \arabicSqrt{31}\\[1.2em]
            arabicsqrt  & \arabicsqrt[3]{42}\\[1.2em]
            arabicSqrt  & \arabicSqrt[3]{31}\\[1.2em]
            arabicsigma & \arabicsigma{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            arabicSigma & \arabicSigma{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            arabicint   & \arabicint{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            arabicInt   & \arabicInt{a}{b}{f(x)}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \centerline{In math mode}\vspace{-17pt}
        \begin{align}
            \text{arabicsqrt}   &= \arabicsqrt{42}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicSqrt}   &= \arabicSqrt{31}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicsqrt}   &= \arabicsqrt[3]{42}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicSqrt}   &= \arabicSqrt[3]{31}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicsigma}  &= \arabicsigma{س}{ب}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicSigma}  &= \arabicSigma{س}{ب}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicint}    &= \arabicint{س}{ب}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \text{arabicInt}    &= \arabicInt{س}{ب}{f(x)}
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

### Edit 1

I have changed the `\arabicsqrt` implementation to accept nth root as well as it is extremely less verbose (hence, easier to understand and change). As an extra, I have include the integral sign as well as two modes: in-text mode and math-mode.

[image: Newer Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Flips the text about the y axis by 180 degrees.
\newcommand{\adj}[1]{\rotatebox{180}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{#1}}}

% In-text sqrt with the nth root option
\newcommand{\arabicsqrt}[2][]{%
    \adj{\ensuremath{\sqrt[\adj{#1}]{\adj{#2}}}}%
}%
% larger sqrt with the nth root option
\newcommand{\arabicSqrt}[2][]{%
    \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sqrt[\adj{#1}]{\adj{#2}}}}%
}%
% In-text summation
\newcommand{\arabicsigma}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\sum_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% larger summation
\newcommand{\arabicSigma}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sum_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% In-text integral
\newcommand{\arabicint}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\int_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%
% Larger summation
\newcommand{\arabicInt}[3]{%
   \adj{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\int_{\adj{#1}}^{\adj{#2}}\adj{\ensuremath{#3}}}}%
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \centerline{In text-mode}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \verb|\arabicsqrt|  & \arabicsqrt{42}\\[1.2em]
            \verb|\arabicSqrt|  & \arabicSqrt{31}\\[1.2em]
            \verb|\arabicsqrt|  & \arabicsqrt[3]{42}\\[1.2em]
            \verb|\arabicSqrt|  & \arabicSqrt[3]{31}\\[1.2em]
            \verb|\arabicsigma| & \arabicsigma{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \verb|\arabicSigma| & \arabicSigma{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \verb|\arabicint|   & \arabicint{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \verb|\arabicInt|   & \arabicInt{a}{b}{f(x)}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \centerline{In math mode}\vspace{-17pt}
        \begin{align*}
            \texttt{arabicsqrt}     &= \arabicsqrt{42}\\[1.2em]
            \texttt{arabicSqrt}     &= \arabicSqrt{31}\\[1.2em]
            \texttt{arabicsqrt}     &= \arabicsqrt[3]{42}\\[1.2em]
            \texttt{arabicSqrt}     &= \arabicSqrt[3]{31}\\[1.2em]
            \texttt{arabicsigma}    &= \arabicsigma{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \texttt{arabicSigma}    &= \arabicSigma{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \texttt{arabicint}      &= \arabicint{a}{b}{f(x)}\\[1.2em]
            \texttt{arabicInt}      &= \arabicInt{a}{b}{f(x)}
        \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

### Original

Here is a start that you can use to implement the functions from scratch.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\arabicsqrt}[1]{
    \scalebox{1}[-1]{%
        \rotatebox{180}{%
            \ensuremath{%
                \sqrt{\rotatebox{180}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{#1}}}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\arabicsigma}[3]{%
    \scalebox{1}[-1]{%
        \rotatebox{180}{%
            \ensuremath{%
                \sum_{\rotatebox{180}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{#1}}}^{\rotatebox{180}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{#2}}}
                {\rotatebox{180}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\ensuremath{#3}}}}
            }%
        }%
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \arabicsqrt{42}\\[2em]
    \arabicsigma{a}{b}{f(x)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ido not think I understand your questions. Symbols and equations do not change orientation in Arabic. The square root stays the same. But if you really need such a transformation, you can use the `\reflectbox` from the `graphicx`. An example is given in this answer:

[Answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116431/199789)

Comment: On the contrary, symbols *do* change orientation in Arabic, at least in (elementary) pedagogical contexts.  See "[RyDArab — Typesetting Arabic mathematical expressions](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-2/tb81lazrek.pdf)" by Azzeddine Lazrek.